# Handcoding PHP for daily log style website with mySQL database

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql

I only began learning about web development 3 weeks ago and have grasped html, css and js quite quickly and have also had some success in using php to draw values from a mySQL database that I have setup however I have a few questions if that is OK?

I am designing a website that essentially allows users to register and then login and add details to a daily log which is stored in the mySQL database. I also want a forum, content section and a shop. Obviously there is no standard open source package for this so I have been investigating how to handcode the PHP to log users in and have them logged in across all parts of the handcoded website. I initially thought I could do this using sessions but I have read that they are bad for SEO? I understand that you can disable them and use cookies but I fear this is all getting a bit over my head? Would it be easier to try and develop this in ASP.NET?

Apologies if some of this doesn't make sense but as I said I am very new to this but I am eager to learn and really serious about it so I will take any information given to me on board. Thanks for your time

Comment: how on earth would sessions be bad for seo? there are a million open source examples of user authentication with PHP on the web. if you want a shortcut, use an open source framework, but learn the language first.

Comment: Hey dqhendricks, I am just quoting what I read here [link](http://webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=219880) I understood that given that using sessions appends sessionIDs to the end of URLs this made them hard for the spiders to crawl and also ran the risk of being penalised for duplicate content. Like I say, I am new to all of this and I am just going on what I have read online, I have no idea if it is accurate

Comment: that is if you allow session ids to be passed via URL, which is not the default and you should not allow it for security reasons anyways. session ids are typically passed via cookie data, which PHP handles transparently in its session handling mechanism. by the way, this is not unique to PHP. all server side languages need to be aware of this.

Comment: OK, thanks very much for clearing that up, I understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all very possible in PHP, but what you are asking is for an explanation that requires a book. Speaking of books, there are tons of great books offering help with exactly what you need:

[PHP 5 CMS Framework Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847193579): Would teach you about many of the pieces you are trying to assemble by hand including MVC principles.

"Obviously there is no standard open source package.."

Just to name one, WordPress allows users to log in and add stuff to a daily log (it's called a blog), has content sections, and has forum and commerce plugins. Personally, I've been amazed at how customizable WordPress is!

Comment: thanks for your quick reply cillosis! I should have been more specific, the users need to be able to add data to a daily log and it is shown to them in a dynamic graph using higcharts javascript framework. Would this all be possible in wordpress? I intended to use WordPress on just the content section to allow me to manage the content but I assumed I would have to code the rest by hand? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that would be possible in WordPress, but like you said, it would require custom coding mostly likely as a plugin. It's hard to give a full answer because there are so many pieces to the puzzle that you need to learn first.

Comment: I totally understand that! thanks for your time, I will try to develop my knowledge further so I can ask a more precise question next time! It has been a very steep learning curve and a lot to take in!

Comment: The learning curve never ends. If it does, you are doing something wrong. The trick is to learn how to climb those obstacles at faster rate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your comment about using cookies instead of sessions.  I recommend you use the [PHP $_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) superglobal to keep users logged in during their session.

If you have super-sensitive data in these logs, one option might be to verify that the user's IP has not changed between requests.

I see no reason why ASP.net would be preferable.  Personally, I like to learn programming by opening up vim and going at it.

P.S. Be sure you are escaping data provided to you by users before writing it to your SQL database.

Comment: checking an ip is not a great solution since one some networks a single user's ip address may change, while on others, all user's may have the same ip address.

Comment: Sorry if it didn't make sense? I intitially intended to use sessions but I read that this was bad in terms of search engine indexing as they may not index the page or record duplicate content, either being bad? I read somewhere that you can use cookies as a replacement to sessions that isnt damaging in terms of SEO? Although I admit I may have misunderstood what they were saying! Thanks for your help!